# How to automatically select files to be uploaded when page loads in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, image, forms, file-upload

I have an application that has a blog post editing form.

My goal is when I open the edit page I want to load all the information about the blog post beforehand, including the files, to the input fields so that users can see what's already there.

Problem is I couldn't select image files programmatically. Do you know a way to do this in PHP?

I have an array of blog posts called $events

I'm using a json file as database. Events array is like this:
`"events": [ { "id": "9eff15b8c4500b42701e3b4af8d66d19", "images": ["etkinlik1.jpg"], ... },... ]`

This is the input element:
`<input id="sendImages" type="file" name="images[]" multiple="multiple" />`

I'm thinking to get the name of the images of the event that is currently selected with this line:
`$events[$currentKey]["images"];`
and use this array to select files beforehand but I have no idea how to select files programmatically in php.

If you have other ideas to reach the goal please mention that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Do you know a way to do this in PHP` why? PHP is server side code, didn't you want to upload from a browser (client) - a browser can't select a file from the client to upload, that has to be done by the user - for obvious security reasons (I may not fully understand the question though, because you seem to want the server to select a file to upload to the server...??)

Comment: when the event has multiple images. I want user to be able to click little tags to remove some of the images and submit the edited file list. Picture like this: [link](https://imgur.com/a/ulAXcPv). In order to do that user must open the page that's images preloaded. But that would be a security issue indeed. I wonder, Is this design pattern not used by others?

Comment: Your logic appears to be based on uploading the whole set of images again every time the post gets edited? That does not make much sense. To keep an already uploaded image, you simply need to _not_ delete it - not upload it again, and again. So separate those two parts (from the logical/ processing point, not necessarily in your UI.) The already uploaded images could be represented in the form by checkboxes - each that gets unchecked, will be removed from the server after submitting the form, the rest will be kept. And any newly uploaded images will be added to storage at this point.

Comment: You can't pre-select files in a file input because that can only pick items from the user's device. So clearly you can't guarantee the right file will exist in the right place, and in any case it would be a security disaster if a website could automatically select files from a device and upload them. So it simply isn't allowed. If you want to show what's already uploaded, add image tags or hyperlinks to show it. And as above, arrange your upload script so existing files aren't deleted if there is nothing selected to replace them

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by not uploading files.

Whole purpose was showing to user what images already uploaded on a blog post. And provide them option to change those images.

When the page first opens I show them the images available but without the removing functionality that way I no longer need to upload files beforehand.
When user loads different set of images they appears as tags which can be removed by clicking on them.

Here is the codepen link of what I'm talking about:
https://codepen.io/nozturk_/pen/QWJoNjK?editors=1111

A small snippet from the code:

```
// Removing Image tag
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  let tagEl = e.target.closest(".tag--image");

  if (tagEl && !tagEl.classList.contains("tag--disabled")) {
    const filename = tagEl.children[0].innerText;

    tagEl.remove();

    for (let i = 0; i < dt.files.length; i++) {
      if (filename === dt.files[i].name) {
        dt.items.remove(i);
      }
    }
    sendImages.files = dt.files;
  }
});
```